# Window title bar width changes when maximized

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I created a demo app in Delphi 11.1 and when I maximize the window, the title bar width gets re-sized (squeezed). Is this the windows' default behavior? How do I prevent it? I just wanted to keep the same title bar width even after the window is maximized.

**Window not maximized:**
[image]
**Window maximized and title bar width is automatically reduced!!**
[image]

Comment: I looks like this is normal, I tried it with a C# WinForms and it was the same there.

Comment: @GuidoG  however, it looks a bit odd.  There should have been a provision to keep the title bar width as it is..

Comment: I agree, the height should not just change without any means of preventing it, but at the moment I don't know how to do it either, sorry

Comment: Yes this is normal. Actually, the system doesn't resize the title bar, but makes the window slightly larger than the screen, so its border and part of the title bar will be clipped. This way users have more screen real estate available. [Mandatory OldNewThing link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150304-00/?p=44543).